# Symfony: How to test a form-field of type collection in a functional test without JavaScript?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm struggling for some time now with the collection form.
I have a collection with of at least 3 included forms. But because included forms are not rendered, I cannot fill them up in functional test.

This is how the collection looks like

```php
->add('references', 'collection', array(
            'type'        => 'reference',
            'allow_add'   => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new C\Count(array(
                    'min'        => 3,
                    'minMessage' => 'You should specify at least 3 references.'
                ))
            )
        ))
```

And when this form is render it looks like

```html
<label class="required">References</label><div id="form_references"
data-prototype="here-is-the-rendered-prototype-of-embedded-form">
```

How could I force Symfony Form to render couple of embedded forms also, without using javascript, so that I could easily functional test them or use them on browser without enabled JS?

One more thing, forms are not bind to Enity/Model but just represent a simple array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I don't have experience with function tests, but perhaps you can somehow manually add references to your form using the same method that Symfony suggests for pre-rendering a collection without using javascript prototyping ....

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Inside of the test controller, you can manually add the number of reference fields you want by adding references to your entity.

```
class ApplicationController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $app = new Application();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            $app->getReferences()->add(array(
                'name' => 'Michael ' . $i,
                'phone' => '1 (555) 555-5555'
            ));
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new ApplicationForm(), $app);
        if ($request->getMethod() === "POST")
        {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // Process and Save the information.
            }
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle::Application:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Inside the template, you can loop through the references, and then render them.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    <h3>References</h3>
    <div class="references">
        {% for reference in form.references %}
            <p>
                {{ form_row(reference.name) }}
                {{ form_row(reference.phone) }}
                {{ form_row(reference.body) }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This method was taken directly from the cookbook ... and perhaps you can create a function in your test that will manually add the references.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm not using class mapper, but array. So the solution was a bit different. But you set me on right track. The solution was just simple to add default data with empty arrays.

    'data'       => array(array(), array(), array())